# Error passing variable to artillery script

Tags: artillery

I am using very simple command to test artillery script and trying to pass variable from the command line.
Command is

`artillery run  -v '{"var1": "value1", "var2": "value2"}' .\test\performance\applications.yml -e development`

It is giving error

```
Variable definition is not valid JSON. Correct example: -v '{"var1": "value1", "var2": "value2"}'
```

I cannot see any difference in my command and the fricking error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is found in one of the artillery forums. Inside quotes needs to be escaped. Their documentation is abysmal.

https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/issues/984